# Does Sitecore have a built in email engine?

Tags: sitecore

I know this may sound like a stupid question, but numerous google searches haven't given me the answer I'm looking for. I see a lot of data on how to format emails based on Sitecore Templates etc, but nothing on actually sending mail. Do I need to do this via .net code, or does Sitecore have a component that manages sending mail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the volume of mail you want to send. If you just want to send simple emails (ie alert emails or 'thank you for registering' type emails then you would just use the normal built-in .NET email functionality.

For more complicated (campaign/mass) emailing there are add-on modules such as the Email Campaign Manager (ECM) - http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/ECM.aspx or http://www.sitecore.net/unitedkingdom/Resources/brochures/Sitecore%20Email%20Campaign%20Manager

Sitecore provides some example auto-emailer actions in the 'Sample Workflow' that comes with the default Sitecore install too.

The [Web forms for Marketers](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers.aspx) module also has some emailing actions that are included with the package.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm just looking for basic functionality so I can create a forum users can fill in, which will send out a single email. No mass emails at this stage. I guess I'll be using the .NET email functionality. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at `Sitecore.MainUtil.SendMail` as a built in function within Sitecore to send email. My understanding is it uses the standard .net mail library, but puts a Sitecore wrapper around it.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look into system.mail.net. The best reference site for this can be found here:

http://www.systemnetmail.com/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the replies.

As with other Sitecore issues, I found that Sitecore was not necessary to solve this issue. Standard .Net functionality did what I wanted much easier.